# Getting from Punta Arenas to El Calafate in July?

Tags: buses, argentina, el-calafate

I'm finding it impossible to find a bus route from Punta Arenas in July to El Calafate. I thought I was meant to stop in Puerto Natales, but apparently no buses run there in July.

So I was told Rio Gallegos but cannot find the bus timetable for this.
Does anyone know?

I want to see the Perito Morino Glacier.

Answer (score 1):

According to [Buses Fernández](http://www.busesfernandez.com/) they run 8 buses a day from Punta Arenas to Puerto Natales "todos los días del año" (ie every day):

[image: Bus time tables]

Incidentally [Turismo Condor](http://www.turismocondor.cl/tour-terrestres/tours-puerto-natales/tours-puerto-natales-full-day-perito-moreno) operate full day trips from Puerto Natales to Perito Moreno (via El Calafate) every day (but have a 4 person minimum).

Comment: In addition, most hostels in El Calafate (eg Hostel America del Sur) offer tours from their front desk.  We did it in July 2010, a day tour to Perito Moreno, and it was fantastic.  [On my blog](http://www.marksmayo.com/2010/07/15/perito-morena-glacier-part-1/)

Comment: I was there for the [2010 solar eclipse](http://apod.nasa.gov/apod/ap100715.html) (I was standing just behind this guy), but yeah it was freezing.  In summer, I gather the hiking is amazing.